# regex for string dates in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

[image]

let's say I have a dataframe with a value strings that looks like like:

```
[26.07. - 08.09.]
```

and I want to add '2018' behind the last '.' before the date ends such that my output will be :

```
[26.07.2018 - 08.09.2018]
```

and apply this for the rest of the dataframe which basically has the same format.

so far I have the code:

```
df.iloc[:,1].replace('.','2018',regex=True)
```

how can I change my code such that it will work as I desire?

I am doing this so that eventually I will be able to transform these into dates that can count how many days are there between the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '[26.07. - 08.09.]'
aWithYear = [i[:-1]+'2018'+i[-1] for i in a.split('-')]

print('-'.join(aWithYear))
# prints [26.07.2018 - 08.09.2018]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have, for example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['[05.07. - 18.08.]', '[05.07. - 18.09.]']})

col
0   [05.07. - 18.08.]
1   [05.07. - 18.09.]
```

You can `split` and concat the `str.get(0)` and `str.get(1)` values

```
vals = df.col.str.strip('[]').str.split("- ")
get = lambda s: vals.str.get(s).str.strip() + '2018'
df['col'] = '[' + get(0) + ' - ' + get(1) + ']'


col
0   [05.07.2018 - 18.08.2018]
1   [05.07.2018 - 18.09.2018]
```